# JSESSIONID or X-AUTH-TOKEN duplicates while authenticating the same user in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

My team has been using **springboot + redis** for securing microservices, by storing the spring-security session in Redis instance allowing single session per user(means a user can login only once at a time, if the user login two times simultaneously, the former session will be invalidated). Everything works perfect most of the time but always.

In some times it has been noted that if a user login two times within a span of 1 mins without logging-out the previous session,  the **jsessionid - or X-auth-token** is duplicated, which means the second session-id is same as the previous one, which is weird, ideally it should invalidates the old one and create a new session, also this does not happens always, only in some cases.

Also note that there are 3 instance of the microservice is running in parallel and points to the same Redis server.

Any one has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: how could anyone fix this? we have no idea what your code looks like, for all that we know you can have written a bad implementation. Please read up on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask. Voted to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete existing login in your JWT Token class first, and then add another token to redis like this:

```
TokenRedisDto dto = (TokenRedisDto) myRedisService.loadById(users.getUsername());
 if (Objects.nonNull(dto)){
     // remove previous logged-in user
     myRedisService.deleteItem(dto.getId());
 }
// add another token here..
myRedisService.addItem(new TokenRedisDto(users.getUsername(), token));
```

I tested it too many times on a load test and operational, in enterprise and individual. Works properly in microservices!